# Graph States subjected to finite erasures

Tags: noise, graph-states

The appendix to the paper [Graph States as a Resource for Quantum Metrology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.05047) states that when graph states subjected to finite erasures, $$G\Rightarrow Tr_\vec{y}G.$$ While more explicitly he explains the formula as
$$G_\vec{y} = \mathrm{const}\times\sum_{\vec{y}}Z_\vec{j}\lvert G\rangle\langle G\rvert Z_\vec{j}.$$
I was wondering, how can these two statements the same, i.e., why the erasure error can be stated as the operation of $Z$? I know $I + Z$ can be the erasure error, but how can $Z$ alone stand for the erasure error?

Comment: Have you checked section $6$ (specifically proposition $8$ on page $46$) of the review article ["entanglement in graph states"](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0602096)? The proof is on the next page.

Comment: I've checked, and the question is amended, avoiding passing the wrong meaning.

Comment: I just realized you changed the question - so that makes my answer moot. Have you tried factoring out the $\frac{1}{2}(I + Z)$? If you delete for instance $2$ qubits, you'll get a summation over $II, ZI, IZ$ and $ZZ$ - exactly a sum over $j \in \{00,01,10,11\}$, or in other words every combination of $0$'s and $1$'s for the traced away qubits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of erasure being projection onto $|0\rangle$ is perhaps misleading in this context (my fault for mentioning it in a comment without having looked at the full details of what this specific paper did). This paper does not project the set of qubits $y$ onto the $|0\rangle$ state. Instead, they trace out those qubits. Perhaps the best way of writing this, to be more consistent with the notation is
$$
G\rightarrow \text{Tr}_yG\otimes \frac{I_y}{2^{|y|}}.
$$
If you think of $G$ as some sum of terms in the Pauli basis,
$$
G=\sum_{x\in\{0,1,2,3\}^n}\alpha_x\sigma_x,
$$
then what the partial trace is doing is selecting all the $x$ for which the $y$ components of $\sigma_x$ are all $I$.

So, let us consider terms
$$
\sum_{z\in\{0,1\}^{n}}'Z_z\sigma_xZ_z.
$$
I'm using the notation $\sum'$ to denote the fact that while $z\in\{0,1\}^n$, I'm only summing over terms where $z$ is 0 on every site not specified by $y$ or the neighbours of $y$ (i.e. those not in the set $L_y$ in the paper's notation).
There are two possibilities for the fixed $x$ and a particular $z$ - either $Z_z$ commutes or anti-commutes with $\sigma_x$.
$$
Z_z\sigma_xZ_z=(-1)^{x'\cdot z}\sigma_x.
$$
Here I'm using $x'$ to denote a binary string derived from $x$ which is 1 for a given site if $x$ yielded an $X$ or $Y$.
Thus,
$$
\sum_{z\in\{0,1\}^{n}}'Z_z\sigma_xZ_z=\sigma_x\sum_{z\in\{0,1\}^{n}}'(-1)^{x'\cdot z}.
$$
This is $2^{|L_y|}\sigma_x$ if $x'$ is 0 on all the sites $y$ and its neighbours. It's 0 otherwise. This immediately excludes any stabilizer (product of generators) that contains a generator (of the form $XZZZ\ldots Z$) where the $X$ acts on one of the sites to be traced out, or one of its neighbours. Since all generators act on a single vertex and its neighbours, this means that the only terms remaining do not act at all on the sites being traced out, i.e. they are $I$ on those sites. Exactly the set of stabilizers you were trying to select.